Jquery Reformat date from a string in a tag?
I try to extract and reorganize a date string? 2024-11-21 into 21-11-2024
Any help would be... Helpful :)
Thanks
I have a string in html
<h2 class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4">2024-11-21</h2>
I want to display date as 21-11-2024
I tried this to extract number
     var number = parseInt(jQuery('.tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4').text());    alert(number);
But fails
How do I extract and reorganize a date string?

parseInt - A date is not an integer.  It's a date.  Have you tried searching for examples of parsing a date in JavaScript?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You could manipulate the String, split it into an array and then re-arrange it in the format you would prefer. Otherwise, bring the Text in and cast it to a Date type. Then format the Date as you like.

You can try like this.


var dateElement = document.querySelector('.tg-item-meta-data.tg-element-4');

var dateString = dateElement.textContent;
var dateParts = dateString .split('-');

var result = `${dateParts[2]}-${dateParts[1]}-${dateParts[0]}`;

dateElement.textContent = result;
<h2 class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4">2024-11-21</h2>



And this is code with jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dateString = $('.tg-item-meta-data.tg-element-4').text(); 

    var dateParts = dateString.split('-');
    var result = dateParts[2] + '-' + dateParts[1] + '-' + dateParts[0];

    $('.tg-item-meta-data.tg-element-4').text(result);
});


I add jQuery( document.querySelector('.tg-item-meta-data.tg-element-4').replaceWith(result) ); 
to display the correct format in the html code but it's not realy working, tag and style are different. Is there another code to replace the previous date by 'result' in the same html line?

Hi, @pierre wacquier. You can't use replaceWith. To replace original date with correct format one in jQuery, you can do like this: $('.tg-item-meta-data.tg-element-4').text(result);

Multiple ways to accomplish this.


jQuery(function($) {
  function modifyDateString(oldString) {
    return oldString.split("-").reverse().join("-");
  }

  function stringToDateFormat(dateString) {
    var newDate = new Date(dateString);
    return newDate.getUTCDate() + "-" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + newDate.getFullYear();
  }

  console.log("1. " + modifyDateString($("h2.tg-item-meta-data").text().trim()));
  console.log("2. " + stringToDateFormat($("h2.tg-item-meta-data").text().trim()));

  $("h2.tg-item-meta-data").text(modifyDateString($("h2.tg-item-meta-data").text().trim()));
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4">2024-11-21</h2>



